# Preserve Original Categorical Mappings while Joining Multiple Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, categorical-data

I have `n` dataframes with one column each, which has dtype `category`. The columns of the different frames have partial overlaps. I want to share the category -> ID mapping between the columns upon joining them into a new frame:

```
In [362]: af = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(['a1','a2', 'b1'], dtype="category", name='a'))

In [365]: bf = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(['b1','b2', 'a1'], dtype="category", name='b'))

In [373]: all_categories = pd.Categorical(['a1','a2','b1','b2'])

In [376]: show_mapping(af.a)
[('a1', 0), ('a2', 1), ('b1', 2)]

In [377]: af.a.cat =  all_categories

In [378]: show_mapping(af.a)
[('a1', 0), ('a2', 1), ('b1', 2), ('b2', 3)]

In [379]: show_mapping(bf.b)
[('b2', 0), ('a1', 1), ('b1', 2)]

In [380]: bf.b.cat =  all_categories

In [381]: show_mapping(bf.b)
[('a1', 0), ('a2', 1), ('b1', 2), ('b2', 3)]
```

Now I join these frames with what I assumed to now be identical mappings:

```
In [382]: df = af.join(bf)
```

But when I print the mapping of the columns, they reset:

```
In [384]: show_mapping(df.a)
[('a1', 0), ('a2', 1), ('b1', 2)]

In [385]: show_mapping(df.b)
[('b2', 0), ('a1', 1), ('b1', 2)]
```

Why are the mappings being redone automatically upon joining the frames and how can I achieve what I intended?

---

```
def show_mapping(x):
    print(list(sorted(zip(x.cat.categories, x.cat.codes), key=lambda x : x[1])))
```

## edit

all confusion came from using a bad show function. The following show function actually works correctly. Combine that with the `set_categories` method instead of `.cat = ...` an everything turns out correctly:

```
def show_mapping(s):
    print([(e, s.cat.codes[i]) for i, e in enumerate(s)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#setting-categories) by `all_categories` for using same categories in each categorical column, so after `join` get same codes:

```
af = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(['a1','a2', 'b1'], dtype="category", name='a'))
bf = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(['b1','b2', 'a1'], dtype="category", name='b'))

def show_mapping(x): 
    return (list(sorted(zip(x.cat.categories, x.cat.codes), key=lambda x : x[1])))
```

---

```
print(af.a)
0    a1
1    a2
2    b1
Name: a, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a1, a2, b1]

all_categories = pd.Categorical(['a1','a2','b1','b2'])

af.a = af.a.cat.set_categories(all_categories)
bf.b = bf.b.cat.set_categories(all_categories)
```

Added category `b2`:

```
print(af.a)
0    a1
1    a2
2    b1
Name: a, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [a1, a2, b1, b2]
```

---

```
print(show_mapping(af.a))
[('a1', 0), ('a2', 1), ('b1', 2)]

print(show_mapping(bf.b))
[('b1', 0), ('a1', 2), ('a2', 3)]

df = af.join(bf)

print(show_mapping(df.a))
[('a1', 0), ('a2', 1), ('b1', 2)]

print(show_mapping(df.b))
[('b1', 0), ('a1', 2), ('a2', 3)]
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how that is "sharing the mapping". The mappings of the columns are still different from each other and precisely not the mapping from `all_categories`.

Comment: In your code `df.b` now is missing the entry for `'b2'` for some reason, also. Why is that?

Comment: @lotolmencre - hmmm, give me some time.

Comment: @lotolmencre - I am a bit confused - `I don't see how that is "sharing the mapping"` - I test `print (af.a.cat.codes)
print (bf.b.cat.codes)`


`df = af.join(bf)`
`print (df.a.cat.codes)
print (df.b.cat.codes)` and same codes, so it seems it working for me. Can you explain more? Why it not working?

Comment: We must be talking past each other. When I print the mapping of `all_categories` I get `[('a1', 0), ('a2', 1), ('b1', 2), ('b2', 3)]`. As you can see that mapping agrees with the mapping of `df.a`, which is `[('a1', 0), ('a2', 1), ('b1', 2)]`. But it does not agree with the mapping of `df.b`, which is `[('b1', 0), ('a1', 2), ('a2', 3)]`. None of the pairs of this mapping match with the mapping of `all_categories`, because their codes differ.

Comment: @lotolmencre - you are right, I find problem with `show_mapping` function - need  `return list((zip(x.cat.categories, x.cat.codes))) `

Comment: Okay, thanks. I still don't quite understand what is going on. But the main confusion stemmed from my show-function not working as I thought it would. When I manually compare the codes, my initial method with `af.a.cat = all_categories` seems to produce the same result as your method with `af.a.cat.set_categories(all_categories)`.